# $f: (X, d) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $f: (X,d)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Show that $f$ is continuous in $X$ iff for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the sets: $\{x:f(x)>c\}$ and $\{x : f(x) < c\}$ are open.

---

I am going to assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard metric. This means we have a function $f$ from two metric spaces. We may then use the following continuity defintion:

$f: X \to Y$ where $X,Y$ are metric spaces. If $U \subset Y$ is an open subset of $Y$, then the set $$f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in U\}$$ is an open subset of $X$.

---

Maybe I can do something about the inverse images of these sets? Does anyone have advice for this exercise?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space with the metric given by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ where $|\,|$ is the absolut value.

Comment: @Pipicito Right! I edited my post probably $5$s before you posted your comment.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? The answer depends on it. (With one definition, the answer is trivial; less so with others.)

Comment: @SimonS I believe I have the correct definition of continuity. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$ s.t $a<b$.

Then $f^{-1}(]a,b[)=\{x\ ; f(x)>a\}\cap \{x\ ; f(x)<b\}$ which is open.

**Note that :** the set $\{]a,b[ \ ; a,b\in \Bbb R , a\leq b\}$ is a basis of the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.

The direct implication   is immediate.

Comment: What does $]a,b[$ mean?

Comment: is the interval $(a,b)$

Comment: Can you explain why this is the answer? In the continuity definition in my post, it states nothing about needing to take intersections.

Comment: If $U$ is an open set of $\Bbb R$ then $U$ is a union on the intervals $I_i$ of the form $I_i=(a_i,b_i)$ ($a_i\leq b_i$). $U=\cup_i (a_i,b_i) $

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You could also note the rays are a pre-base.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I have not yet learned what those are yet. A quick Google search doesn't bring anything up. Do you mind explaining what that is?

Comment: A set is a pre-base for the topology $\tau$ if the set of finite intersections of its elements is a base for $\tau$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff [basis of topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29)